# PHP export data to xls with pivot tables

Tags: php, excel, pivot-table

How can I export data in PHP to excel spreadsheet that also has pivot tables? Is there any good tutorial about it? Thanks

Comment: hop this will help you http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/a-simple-class-to-export-data-to-excel-using-php.html and other is http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7425

Comment: @Toms - neither is capable of building a pivot table in the files they produce.... the first is generating a tab-separated value file, while the second is producing a csv file (and neither even uses PHP's built-in fputcsv() function)

Answer (score 7):

For an export to include pivot tables, you have precisely three options.

- Ilia Alshanetsky's [Excel extension](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) (xls only, and requires commercial component)
- PHP's [COM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) (requires a COM enabled spreadsheet program such as MS Excel or OpenOffice Calc running on the server)
- The Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)) (requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled)

Comment: From those I could probably use only the first one since it's a server without GUI. What is commercial component?

Comment: The commercial component is the libXL library. Ilia's page does provide a link to this